# NullReferenceException in StartCoroutine method

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

Maybe it's a repeated subject in the community but other answers didn't solved my question...

I tried as the tutorial: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11021/how-can-i-send-and-receive-data-to-and-from-a-url.html and worked fine in start method but when I try:

```
public Class A
 {
 //    ...CODE...
 new B().JSONRequest(jsonString);
 }

public Class B
{

public void JSONRequest(string json) { 
string url = URL.LOCAL.url;
Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
WWW request = new WWW(url, encoding.GetBytes(requisicaoJSON.ToCharArray()), HashtableToDictionary<string, string>(postHeader));
 print("Request: "+request); 

StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(request));
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
        // check for errors
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.data);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
        }    
    }  
}
```

It gives me in the StartRoutine line:
*NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (IEnumerator routine) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineMonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:61*

Console prints *Request: UnityEngine.WWW* so it does not appear to be null. –

Comment: Wait a sec, B is a MonoBehaviour, right? You should attach your B instance to a GameObject using `gameObject.AddComponent<B>()` - Unity warns you not to try to construct MonoBehaviours by saying `new B()` - I would not expect Coroutines to work on a floating MonoBehaviour that's not attached to a GameObject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of background on this:

StartCoroutine is a method provided by the MonoBehaviour base class.

MonoBehaviours are designed to be attached as components to GameObjects - Unity will warn you if you try to construct one with `new`, instead you should create them via `gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviourType>()`

The GameObject is how the engine keeps track of MonoBehaviours from one frame to the next, so it's critical to methods designed to execute over multiple frames, ie. Coroutines. During `StartCoroutine()`, Unity will try to register the relationship between the coroutine and its parent GameObject  (so that if the GameObject is destroyed/disabled, its coroutines can be stopped and not leaked). If it doesn't find a GameObject it will throw a null reference exception.

So, the fix is to ensure every MonoBehaviour is created as part of a GameObject - never construct them free-floating.